# Eclipse cannot publish project to Web-logic due to "missing coherence.jar"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, weblogic

This is the Error message for building the Project to WebLogic Server.
The project can be build in cmd, but it cannot be publish to server.

Eclipse prompt the below messages when the eclipse started.

```
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central (http://artifact:8081/artifactory/repo) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 has not been downloaded from it before.

Error: "coherence.jar" not found. Coherence descriptor files will not work properly.
Missing nested property build_component_config = ${component_root_dir}/dom/config Please check property declaration for this variable.
Missing nested property build_component_logs = ${component_root_dir}/dom/logs Please check property declaration for this variable.
```

The is the ERROR messages when publish in a started Server:

```
Publishing failed
Module named 'DOM_ear' failed to deploy. See Error Log view for more detail.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: No persistence unit named 'SALPU' is available in scope /dom. Available persistence units: [JPATXNFODECommonPU]
Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
Module named 'PRS_ear' failed to deploy. See Error Log view for more detail.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "FWConfigLoaderServlet" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "/prs".
com.oocl.csc.frm.config.loader.FWConfigLoadingException: Initial Loading of configuration parameters fails, please refer to error stack trace for details
    at com.oocl.csc.frm.config.loader.FWConfigLoader.loadConfig(FWConfigLoader.java:76)
    at com.oocl.csc.frm.integration.configuration.loader.FWConfigurationLoader.initConfig(FWConfigurationLoader.java:44)
    at com.oocl.csc.frm.integration.configuration.loader.servlet.FWConfigLoaderServlet.init(FWConfigLoaderServlet.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1981)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1955)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3155)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:487)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:201)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:249)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:28)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:672)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:59)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:164)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Can't load global configuration file : config.xml resulting Document object is null
    at com.oocl.frm.config.util.DocumentLoader.loadFrom(DocumentLoader.java:48)
    at com.oocl.frm.config.util.DocumentLoader.loadGlobalConfig(DocumentLoader.java:105)
    at com.oocl.frm.config.component.GlobalConfigComponent.loadAllConfigFromApp(GlobalConfigComponent.java:407)
    at com.oocl.frm.config.component.GlobalConfigComponent.loadAllConfigFromApp(GlobalConfigComponent.java:391)
    at com.oocl.frm.config.component.GlobalConfigComponent.loadAllConfigFromApp(GlobalConfigComponent.java:373)
    at com.oocl.csc.frm.config.loader.FWConfigLoader.loadConfig(FWConfigLoader.java:53)
    ... 44 more

Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
```